# casting to base generic class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

My base controller  is as follows :

```
public abstract class BaseController<T, VM> : Controller
        where VM : BaseViewModel
        where T : Entity
    {}
```

Derived Controller is  as follows :

```
public partial class HomeController : BaseController<Product,ProductViewModel>
    {
    }
```

In a action filter class,
    I want to cast homecontroller to base controller to access basecontroller properties
    it does not work.
    or is there any other way to get base controller properties using reflection
   **could any one tell whether it is possible?**

```
public class DataUpdaterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                  **var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;** 

        }    }
```

Comment: tags: `[generics]`  `[casting]` - EPIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant cast it directly to BaseController without knowing what T is. You can cast it down to Entity...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController<Entity, ViewModel>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, given a generic type like `SomeGenericType<T1,T2>`, if you have an instance of it, say

```
SomeGenericType<int,string> myInstance ;
```

Or a subtype of it, say

```
class MyWidget : SomeGenericType<AbstractWidget,AbstractGadget> { ... }
....
MyWidget widgetInstance ;
```

Without knowing the particulars of the type parameters (`T1` and `T2` here) involved, there's no way to upcast the instance to what appears to inherit from. In the above examples, while you could cast `myInstance` to `SomeGenericType<int,string>` and `widgetInstance` to `SomeGenericType<AbstractWidget,AbstractGadget>`, there's no way to cast either of them to `SomeGenericType<?,?>`.

This is because an instance of a generic type does not really inherit from the base generic type in the usual sense.

Further, given something like

```
class A { ... }
class B : A { ... }

SomeGenericType<B> instance ;
```

You can't even upcast `instance` like this:

```
SomeGenericType<A> upcast = (SomeGenericType<A>) instance ;
```

There's lots of times I don't particularly care about the particulars of the type parameters of the generic type: I find this a huge fail on the part of C#'s design, though I'm sure the designers had their reasons.

Answer (score 0):

C# and CTS (Common Type System) do not permit casting to an open generic type like that. If you have properties in `BaseController<,>` that don't depend on the type arguments, you have two options: create a non-generic interface `IBaseController`, list those properties in it and have `BaseController<,>` implement this interface, or create a non-generic (possibly abstract) base class for `BaseController<,>` and put the properties into this base class. This is often a good idea regardless of whether you need to cast to `BaseController` or not.

By the way, sometimes you can also create non-generic versions of properties whose types depend on type parameters, e.g. in your case `IBaseController` could have a property `Entity Entity {get;}`.